# Messaging mysql table query

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, output

I'm trying to implement a messaging system, but with a slight twist.
Messages can only be started from user 2 to user 1.
This starting message has the start = 1 value.

```
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+----- -----+-------+---------------------+
| id (ai) | user1id  | user2id  | originated| to_user2  | start | messag              | 
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| 1       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    0      |   1   | Hi                  | 
| 2       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    1      |   0   | Hi back             | 
| 3       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    0      |   0   | So Whats up         | 
| 4       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    1      |   0   | Nothing much, why   | 
| 5       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    0      |   0   | Just checking       | 
| 6       |  1       | 2        |  1234     |    1      |   0   | OK                  | 
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
```

So I'm able to get the starting message by doing WHERE start = '1'.

I'm able to get the messages from user1 to user2 doing WHERE to_user2 = '1'

I'm able to get the messages from user2 to user1 by doing WHERE to_user2 = '0' and start='0'

Right? following me?

How would I make my query so that I get the following output:

```
STARTING MESSAGE  (id 1)
 message to user2  (id 2)          

              message to user 1  (id3)
              message to user 2  (id4)

                      message to user 1  (id5)
                      message to user 2  (id6)
```

I hope im making some sense.

Let me clarify that im able to get this output using 6 different querys, but i wonder if thats the way to go, and if its possible in 1 query.

Comment: cant u use or conditions in clause to get them all?

Comment: could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: I will better make it an answer, so that you can help me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table
WHERE  user2_id = some_id 
   AND (start = 1  OR to_user2 = 1 OR (to_user2 = 0 AND start = 0))
```

Comment: this would give me all the messages yes, but that will not display them in order

Comment: in which order do you want?

Comment: how would i adjust this query, i tried but cant seem to get it to work, to also check current user id and show only his ofcourse

Comment: i tried adding "WHERE user2_id = '$u_id'" where u_id is being set by the login system. but that breaks the query

Comment: is current user represented by `user2_id`?

Comment: yes it is , it should ONLY display the messages based on current user (user2_id)

Comment: @defiancenl catch my update. These things are actually very simple, once you get the hang of it. Btw, I dont know whats with `'$u_id'`, I'm not a php guy. You will have to make it a separate question. What do you mean by break? Receives exceptions or gives wrong results?

Comment: @defiancenl thats where the problem is. See the parentheses in my query. In yours you have not used it wisely I believe.